[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "lodash/throttle" from "node_modules/tdesign-mobile-vue/es/index.js"
npm run dev is fine. npm run build throws an error;
vue3 + vite + tdesign-mobile-vue;
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "lodash/throttle" from "node_modules/tdesign-mobile-vue/es/index.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
build.rollupOptions.external
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "lodash/throttle" from "node_modules/tdesign-mobile-vue/es/index.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
build.rollupOptions.external
Hope it's packed properly

Have you tried to add it to build.rollupOptions.external?
